# Why does Laravel redirect me to the login page even though im still logged in?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I used `php artisan make:auth` in my laravel project to automatically create my login and registration pages.

Even though I'm still logged in when I leave my page for a few minutes and then go back to my laravel project page it redirects to the login page.

I know i'm logged in because I can see it on the upper part of the login page if user wasn't logged in it would display two buttons login and register and if user was already logged in it would just display my username which it did and also the fact that I can go to my dashboard page by just manually typing it in the url which shouldn't be allowed if user wasn't logged in :(

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a route of your dashboard

```
Route::route('/home', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

You just need to use `auth` middleware in order to add page visits restrictions.

You may check more authentication detail here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication